What informatics tools will allow complex search in order to select full-text articles?
I'd like to search plant science literature (full text) to only return articles in which the word "three" appears four or more times in the full-text Methods section (presumably the best source of this information would be pubmed central). I've looked at scite - and this accepts json and regex - but apparently only searches citations rather than full-text methods. Perhaps it's possible to write a query which uses json and regex to query https://europepmc.org/ to perform this specific action ? An alternative would be to use informatics tools to download huge amounts of data from PubMed and then construct R (or other) programming in order to search through the downloaded dataset. This question is about what is the most effective way forward in order to achieve this ? I have extensive R coding experience, Python shouldn't be a problem - I've been advised that an API would probably first be needed - and then NLP (natural language processing), particularly a technique called "stemming" and "tokenising", or perhaps the large language model langchain ?

I'm not sure about fetching or directly searching, but if you do collect the documents, something like "the word 'three' appears four or more times in the [...] Methods section" should be quite a lot easier than general NLP: no stemming or tokenising is needed, just a count of one specific word, after splitting by section and identifiying the Methods one?

@BenReiniger - Yes - my main concern is that many thousands of full-text articles would have to be collected first - is this the way this is normally achieved ? perhaps I'm worrying too much (?) - roughly how many full-texts - or just the methods sections - could I fit onto a hard drive (or perhaps somewhere else ?)

Someone else is likely to have better feedback on that part.  But you could pull one or a batch of documents, analyze them, delete them, then repeat, instead of trying to allocate space for all of them at once.

@BenReiniger. Good point ! In that case (unless someone advises a direct fetch option) I presume I need to start looking at a PubMed Central (PMC) API ? Any ideas which to try first :  PMC Cloud Service, PMC OAI-PMH Service, PMC FTP Service, E-Utilities and BioC API ? Perhaps the last one is accessible through R ?

Yes - amazingly there is An R Client for the Europe PubMed Central RESTful Web Service (see https://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService for more information). It gives access to both metadata on life science literature and open access full texts. I'll start there - many thanks
